# Prove that every group of order $p^m$ with $p$ a prime number can be generated by $m$ elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, p-groups

Prove that every group of order $p^m$ can be generated by $m$ elements, where $p$ is a prime number.

I am thinking about induction.

Base case: if $m=1$, then $|G|=p$. So $G$ is cyclic. Hence, it's generated by $1$ element.

Suppose this is true for all $k<m$.

Now let $|G|=p^m$.

By the class equation, we know that $p$ divides the centre of $G$, $Z(G)$. So the centre is non-trivial.

Hence, $|Z(G)|=p^k$ for some $k\leq m$.

If $k=m$, then by the Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian Groups, we're done.

Now we only need to deal with the case $k<m$.

I tried to look for the generators of $G$ from the projection map $\pi: G \rightarrow \frac{G}{Z(G)}$. But I'm a bit stuck here.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Apply the induction hypothesis to $G/Z(G)$ and $Z(G)$.

Comment: I see that we have $|\frac{G}{Z(G)}|=p^l$ for some $l<m$ and $l+k=m$. But I'm not sure what the generators of $G$ are here. My guess is that we could probably somehow use the cosets of $\frac{G}{Z(G)}$ (and use 3rd isomorphism theorem?) and the generators of $Z(G)$ to get $m$ elements, I'm not sure how exactly that works though.

Comment: It actually looks pretty straightforward to me.  Take $g\in G$.  The $Z(G)$ cosets partition $G$.  So $g$ is in one.  This allows you to write $g=hk$, where $h,k$ are words in the $x_i,y_i$ respectively.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that it makes sense to do induction a little differently.

Let's choose a subgroup $H$ in the group $G$ that $|G:H|=p$ (is there such a subgroup?) Clearly $|H|=p^{m-1}$. By inductive assumption the subgroup $H$ has at most $m-1$ generators. Let $g\in G$ and $g\notin H$. Then $G=\langle H,g\rangle$ (also requires justification). It follows that $G$ has at most $m$ generators.

**Addition.**

Here is another way to perform induction. It uses only the Lagrange theorem.

Let's construct an increasing chain of subgroups
$$
\{e\}=H_0<H_1<H_2<\ldots<H_s=G,
$$
where $H_i=\langle H_{i-1},g_i\rangle$, $g_i\notin H_{i-1}$, for each $i$ ($0<i<s$).
Since by the Lagrange theorem $|H_i|=p^{k_i}$ and $0=k_0<k_1<\ldots<k_s=m$, the length of this chain is at most $m$, that is, $s\leq m$. Besides, $H_i$ is generated by $i$ elements.